# Android TextView Problem

Tags: android, xml, textview, multiline

I have a textview, for some cases it has long text. For long text, it appears so long that so that its distorted the total layout. I want for long text, it should appear in multi-lines. Here is xml for TextView

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottomText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/text_searchword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">
</TextView>
```

What is solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `android:lines` property like Heiko Rupp points out and also set either `android:maxLenght` or `android:maxEms` too.

Both will limit your `TextView` either to a maximum of x pixels or density independent pixels or to x ems accordingly.

Comment: is it possible that make the font size smaller if needed(i.e. for long text) and accommodate it in one line?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to add a lines attribute:

```
android:lines="4"
```

Also `wrap_content` may not be the best choice for the width. Check `fill_parent`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the `android:layout_width =` a specific size.

Answer (score 0):

I think setting the gravity to "center" in the xml file might do the job:

```
    android:gravity="center"
```